# REST API in Spring Boot Application not throwing Bad request though I am passing incorrect properties of the input POJO

Tags: spring, rest, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

This is my REST API:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test1")
public String test1(@RequestBody TestPOJO tpj) {
    if(tpj instanceof TestPOJO) {
        System.out.println("Correct data format passed ");
    }
    return "working1";

}
```

This is structure of TestPOJO:

```
public class TestPOJO {

    private String x;
    private String y;


    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(String y) {
        this.y = y;
    }   
}
```

In POSTMAN client I am passing this requestbody to this API:

```
{
"sd":"u",
"egergdrg":34
}
```

Its printing "Correct data format passed ".Why this input structure is taken as a instance of "TestPOJO". I am passing completely different property inside the body even with different type of data. Isn't it supposed to give 400 Bad Request error ? Why its running successfully? **How can I validate all the incoming request body is having proper structure similar to input parameter and if not return 400 error?**

FYI Dependency added in pom.xml are "spring-boot-starter-web", "spring-boot-starter-test", "spring-boot-devtools".

Comment: And wy should it throw an exception? The request is perfectly valid, how should it now that you don't want to process these parameters in a different way (filter, interceptor, listener or whatever). It just sees that you don't have any properties for binding and as such you will get an empty object.

Comment: @M.Deinum Got your point. Then how can I interpret/validate the incoming requests to my API are in correct format i.e similar structure as of my input POJO

Comment: This is beacuse Spring will create new instance for you, no matter if it is present in the request or no.

Comment: @Antoniossss Any suggestions how to validate the input structure and return error code 401 if input structure is invalid

Comment: Use `@RequestBody`. This way request input will be parsed directly to POJO and will eventually fail if deserialization is not possible.

Comment: @Antoniossss that I have tried , its working in the same way

Comment: Assuming you are using Jackson as parsing lib, add @JsonProperty(required = true) to required properties.

Comment: Yes jackson is being used here. Applying this annotation also , it s working in same way. Anyway I need a generic way to validate the structure of all my entity classes

Comment: I ran your source code, and got **200** as status code and **working1** as response body by Postman.

Comment: @LHCHIN Correct. How to fix it. How to make all such APIs return 401 instead by validating teh input structure ?

Comment: Why would you want to return a 401? What does this have to do with security?

Comment: @M.Deinum   I want to notify consumer of the API that your input format is wormg.

Comment: Again what has that to do with a 401 that is a 400 not a 401.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes it should be 400.. my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your request body. Just annotate your reqúest body like this `@Valid @RequestBody TestPOJO tpj` then in your POJO Class, add e.g. following annotations to the fields:

`@Size(min=5, max=5)
private String x;`

which would actually check the length of the String x.

You can use more annotations, relying in the `javax.annotation` package.
Keep in minde that you need an annotation processor to make it work, e.g. `hibernate-validator-annotation-processor`

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this tutorial - [Validating Form Input](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) on Spring official website.

I modified your source as follows and tested it with Postman, now it will return **400 (Bad Request)**. And I don't think it should return 401 for wrong input data.

Your TestPOJO:

```
public class TestPOJO {
    @NotNull
    private String x;

    @NotNull
    private String y;


    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(String y) {
        this.y = y;
    }   
}
```

Your REST API:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test1")
public String test1(@Valid @RequestBody TestPOJO tpj) {
    if(tpj instanceof TestPOJO) {
        System.out.println("Correct data format passed ");
    }
    return "working1";

}
```

BTW, once you add the dependency of `spring-boot-starter-web` into your pom file, the `hibernate-validator` will be added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

this is because of the updates on the latest springboot version regarding the object mapper FailOnUnknownProperties. if you add this bean to your configuration, you will get 400 as expected

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder mapperBuilder() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().failOnUnknownProperties(true);
}
```